# What's wrong with this model and rig? (It became super deformed.)

Tags: modeling, rigging

I've been struggling with this bunny model and trying to rig it for animation for a while. I made the model in Rhino 5 and imported it to Blender. But when I did, it went from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

The bunny became really deformed and it also scaled up A LOT.

Could someone kindly let me know what's wrong/direct me to proper tutorials on how to fix this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: You probably have some problems with bone weights. Did you bind the rig to the mesh yourself or did it come with it bound already? The rig or some bones also probably has transformations (scale in particular), which affect the model and cause it to scale.
If you're unfamiliar with rigging and weight painting, start with these two tutorials:
https://cgcookie.com/archive/blender-introduction-to-character-rigging/
http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-rigging/

Comment: @TLousky Hi! I did try to bind the rig to the mesh myself. Do you suppose the model is too small/bones are too large? How do I get rid of those weird "transformations"? I'm a little confused, but I will follow the tutorials you linked as well!

Comment: In your rig there's the base skeleton (which contains what's called "deform bones", the bones that should directly influence the mesh), and four bones that lie outside the mesh next to the arms and legs. These bones seem like they're meant to be used as "control bones" - bones that usually provide you with a shortcut for more complex behavior than direct deformation. However, if you don't set these bones to not deform, they will also bind your mesh if you bind with automatic weights and cause unpredictable behavior.